# SQL Server check for prior record only

Tags: sql, sql-server, record

I have these columns: type(char), date , price.
I would like to check if the same type's price has not changed in the previous record.

I tried this for start:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.date > t2.date and t1.type = t2.type
```

I only want to check for the date prior not for every date that is smaller.

This table stores price changes.

| product_type | change_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'A' | 2020.02.18 | 500 |
| 'A' | 2020.02.20 | 750 |
| 'A' | 2020.02.22 | 800 |
| 'B' | 2020.02.22 | 500 |
| 'B' | 2020.02.27 | 900 |
| 'C' | 2020.02.22 | 400 |
| 'C' | 2020.02.29 | 700 |

I want to put this table next to it self to see if the price remained unchanged like this:

| product_type | change_date | price | product_type | change_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'A' | 2020.02.20 | 750 | 'A' | 2020.02.18 | 500 |
| 'A' | 2020.02.22 | 800 | 'A' | 2020.02.20 | 750 |
| 'B' | 2020.02.27 | 900 | 'B' | 2020.02.22 | 500 |
| 'C' | 2020.02.29 | 700 | 'C' | 2020.02.22 | 400 |

I only want to display rows that show no price change, so `price = previous price`.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: If you only want to check the one closest prior data instead of all the prior data, I think you can just use `lag()` or `lead()`.

Comment: however I strongly recommend do not use `date` or `type` as your column name, especially those are reserved keywords, it will be better simply adding some prefix like : `table_date` .

Comment: Is it possible to do this with self join?

Comment: The 90's called - they want their old-style joins back. So [don't use them](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: @SMor there's nothing wrong with using the 'old-style' joins if you know what you're doing, especially when you write a lot of queries (e.g. for reporting/analysis), as it is much faster because the syntax is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    lag(price) over(partition by type order by date) as previous_price 
from table t
```

Comment: How do i filter it down for price = previous_price?

Comment: @Panke put the entire above query in a subquery and then select from it. For example, if we label the above query as X (for readability), then select * from (X) where price = previous_price

Comment: Will try out later, Thanks for your answer!